# Does the assumption of Normal errors imply that Y is also Normal?

Tags: regression, assumptions

Unless I'm mistaken, in a linear model, the distribution of the response is assumed to have a systematic component and a random component. The error term captures the random component. Therefore, if we assume that the error term is Normally distributed, doesn't that imply that the response is also Normally distributed? I think it does, but then statements such as the one below seem rather confusing:

> And you can see clearly that the only assumption of "normality" in
>   this model is that the residuals (or "errors" $\epsilon_i$) should be
>   normally distributed. **There is no assumption about the distribution of
>   the predictor $x_i$ or the response variable $y_i$**.

Source: [Predictors, responses and residuals: What really needs to be normally distributed?](http://www.petrkeil.com/?p=393)

Comment: If the $x$'s are non-stochastic the normality of $\epsilon$ implies normality of the dependent variable.  For stochastic independent variables this will not hold in general, it then depends on the distribution of the independent variables.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The standard OLS model is $Y = X \beta + \varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal N(\vec 0, \sigma^2 I_n)$ for a *fixed* $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$.

This does indeed mean that $Y|\{X, \beta, \sigma^2\} \sim \mathcal N(X\beta, \sigma^2 I_n)$, although this is a consequence of our assumption on the distribution of $\varepsilon$, rather than actually being the assumption. Also keep in mind that I'm talking about the conditional distribution of $Y$, not the marginal distribution of $Y$. I'm focusing on the conditional distribution because I think that's what you're really asking about.

I think the part that is confusing is that this *doesn't* mean that a histogram of $Y$ will look normal. We are saying that the entire vector $Y$ is a single draw from a multivariate normal distribution where each element has a potentially different mean $E(Y_i|X_i) = X_i^T\beta$. This is not the same as being an iid normal sample. The errors $\varepsilon$ actually are an iid sample so a histogram of them would look normal (and that's why we do a QQ plot of the residuals, not the response).

Here's an example: suppose we are measuring height $H$ for a sample of 6th graders and 12th graders. Our model is $H_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1I(\text{12th grader}) + \varepsilon_i$ with $\varepsilon_i \sim \ \text{iid} \ \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$. If we look at a histogram of the $H_i$ we'll probably see a bimodal distribution, with one peak for 6th graders and one peak for 12th graders, but that doesn't represent a violation of our assumptions.

Comment: Could someone please clarify notation $\sigma^2 I_n$?

Comment: It means the $n \times n$ identity matrix multiplied by a scalar $\sigma^2$.

Comment: The $n\times n$ identity matrix times some variance.

Answer (score 12):

> Therefore, if we assume that the error term is Normally distributed, doesn't that imply that the response is also Normally distributed?

Not even remotely. The way I remember this is that the residuals are normal *conditional on the deterministic portion of the model*. Here's a demonstration of what that looks like in practice.

I start by randomly generating some data. Then I define an outcome which is a linear function of the predictors and estimate a model.

```
N <- 100

x1 <- rbeta(N, shape1=2, shape2=10)
x2 <- rbeta(N, shape1=10, shape2=2)

x <- c(x1,x2)
plot(density(x, from=0, to=1))

y <- 1+10*x+rnorm(2*N, sd=1)

model<-lm(y~x)
```

Let's take a look at what these residuals look like. I suspect that they should be normally distributed, since the outcome `y` had iid normal noise added to it. And indeed that is the case.

[image]

```
plot(density(model$residuals), main="Model residuals", lwd=2)
s <- seq(-5,20, len=1000)
lines(s, dnorm(s), col="red")

plot(density(y), main="KDE of y", lwd=2)
lines(s, dnorm(s, mean=mean(y), sd=sd(y)), col="red")
```

Checking the distribution of y, however, we can see that it's definitely not normal! I've overlaid the density function with the same mean and variance as `y`, but it's obviously a terrible fit!

[image: Density of y]

The reason that this happened in this case is that the input data is not even remotely normal. Nothing about this regression model requires normality except in the residuals -- not in the independent variable, and not in the dependent variable.

[image: Denisty of x]

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't. For example, suppose we have a model predicting the weight of Olympic athletes.  While weight could well be normally distributed among athletes in each sport, it won't be among all athletes - it might not even be unimodal.